# PHP: mail form not submitting correctly

Tags: php, html, forms, submit, form-submit

I have an HTML form on a website that is not submitting any information. The HTML file and the PHP file for the form are in the same directory, and when I try to submit the form it simply takes me to `website_name/mail.php` and I dont receive any emails.

I looked on stack and googled it and most of the time it was because the name attribute from the fields was missing, but I have them on there. I would appreciate any help or input from anybody that could help me out with this.

This is my section of code for the HTML form:

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
<br style="clear:both">
    <h3>Contact Us Today!</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" id="message" placeholder="Message" maxlength="140" rows="7"></textarea>
    <span class="help-block"><p id="characterLeft" class="help-block "></span>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn-primary  btn-block">Submit Form</button>
</form>
```

And this is the code for my php form which is named mail.php

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$call = $_POST['call'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$priority = $_POST['priority'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent= "From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Call Back: $call \n Website: $website \n Priority: $priority \n Type: $type \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "cesarm2333@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='form.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Home</a>";
?>
```

When i submit this, I just see a white page at the url websiteName/mail.php
which was redirected from websiteName/index.php

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: yes that made it work! I had to fix some variable names that were not corresponding to each other and some that were not being used at all, but that made the form submit to my email. thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in the form, one of the field names was `mobile`, but the PHP code was trying to get `$_POST['phone']`

That may be a reason

Answer (score 0):

Few input fields you have not used in mail.php. That may be one of the reason.
Use this code.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['mobile'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent= "From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Call Back: $call \n Website: $website \n Priority: $priority \n Type: $type \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "cesarm2333@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='form.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Home</a>";
?>
```